# Setting the learning rate in convolutional neural network

Tags: machine-learning, keras, python-3.7

I am using google collab to learn some CNN's.

I am using model.compile() to set my loss and optimizer function.

Where do I alter learning rate in the following code?

```
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of passing a string you could pass an [optimizer](https://keras.io/optimizers/) to compile method and set your learning rate to the optimizer as shown below:

```
from keras import optimizers
optm = optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, amsgrad=False)
model.compile(optimizer=optm,
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```